# Swift_TransportException error while signup in yii2 advance template

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

i am using yii2 advanced template and facing problem while sign up in sending email.
i have used mailtrap to send email and included all details in common/config/mainlocal-php.
Using Xampp As host.

maillocal.php looks like:

```
<?php
return [
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
            'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=advanced_yii2',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => '',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ],
        'mail' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
                'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
                'useFileTransport' => false,
                'transport' => [
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
                    'username' => '9**************e',
                    'password' => '7***************5',
                    'port' => '2525',
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
    ],
    ],
];

This is the error i am getting.

Swift_TransportException
Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.
]
1. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php at line 299
2. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php at line 54 – Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer::establishProcessConnection()
3. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php at line 143 – Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer::initialize(['timeout' => 30, 'blocking' => 1, 'command' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs', 'type' => 16])
4. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Transport\SendmailTransport.php at line 50 – Swift_Transport_AbstractSmtpTransport::start()
5. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-swiftmailer\src\Mailer.php at line 113 – Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport::start()
6. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-swiftmailer\src\Mailer.php at line 156 – yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::getSwiftMailer()
7. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMailer.php at line 263 – yii\swiftmailer\Mailer::sendMessage(yii\swiftmailer\Message)
8. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\mail\BaseMessage.php at line 49 – yii\mail\BaseMailer::send(yii\swiftmailer\Message)
9. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\models\SignupForm.php at line 77 – yii\mail\BaseMessage::send()
10. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\models\SignupForm.php at line 57 – frontend\models\SignupForm::sendEmail(common\models\User)
11. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\controllers\SiteController.php at line 156 – frontend\models\SignupForm::signup()
12. frontend\controllers\SiteController::actionSignup()
13. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php at line 57 – call_user_func_array([frontend\controllers\SiteController, 'actionSignup'], [])
14. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php at line 157 – yii\base\InlineAction::runWithParams(['r' => 'site/signup'])
15. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php at line 528 – yii\base\Controller::runAction('signup', ['r' => 'site/signup'])
16. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php at line 103 – yii\base\Module::runAction('site/signup', ['r' => 'site/signup'])
17. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php at line 386 – yii\web\Application::handleRequest(yii\web\Request)
18. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii-application\frontend\web\index.php at line 17 – yii\base\Application::run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think issue in `mail`, you should use `mailer` nested of `mail`

for example:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => 'username',
                'password' => 'password',
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

And this is [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer/doc/api/2.1/yii-swiftmailer-mailer)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested this setting through my swiftmailer account and can confirm that the registration email submitted via the signup reached the email account entered under signup. Hence going through mailtrap account below that I setup and was successful. I normally use the dummy account that I setup under my broadband provider so that I can bypass hmailserver which I had difficulty setting up. I use port 25 to connect through my broadband provider normally so I decided to use 25 for mailtrap as well.

```
    <?php
    'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'enableSwiftMailerLogging' =>false,
            //set useFileTransport to true to send to log file
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => ['class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                            'host' => 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
                           'username' => 'f8b66f8dc0eac1',
                            'password' => 'd5da52313fcdd9',
                            'port' => '25',
                           //'encryption' => 'tls',
                           ] 
            ],
            ?>
```

Incidently I am using sjaak/pluto for signup and am very satisfied with this new module.